# How can i receive the REST API request in Mule?

Tags: rest, mule, jira, mule-studio, webhooks

I have used local JIRA Server and i am using Webhook integration concept in JIRA. Here i am giving the Webhook URL is "localhost:8081/webhook" and Event is Create and Update issue. when i am create or update issue means it will be pass to "localhost:8081/webhook". The same address only i gave in mule also but its not working in my MULE. Mule didn't listen the webservice. How can i USE REST API in mule. Which flow is used for receive the JSON format REST API data. It's possible means how can i do this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do this in Mule now is to use the new Api Kit and write your service description in RAML.

Intro material with docs and examples at: ww.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/APIkit

Comment: No it should by using Rest API Component only. don't use the API KIT component. How can i do receive the JSON format by using REST API.

Comment: RAML is good Option but same how it will br working on REST Component

Answer (score 0):

The mule http components may be outboud e.g call your rest api or inbound where the mule server will listen for an event on a http port and url

You say mule is not listening, you should be able to quite simply setup a mule inbound http component flow .. and trigger this flow by pointing your browser at it. I think you will find mule is listening correctly, and you may have mis-configured some of your settings?

Comment: my http components it's inbound only. i am asking REST API. How i can receive the REST API Request by using REST component in mule. The REST API coming for JSON format. How i can receive the request from MULE?

Comment: Yes now i correct the Inbound Mistake its working fine now mule listen the Rest API. but how can i receive the data. the format is coming for JSON. Any way. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The data is in the message payload.

Comment: No its not in message payload.